# Lock keyboard - Ignore input, leave mouse working

Tags: windows, keyboard

I'm looking for a small utility that would allow me to ignore keyboard input, to release it I would have to click some key combination. The same keyboard locking we today have with the Nokia phones.

Please note: I not looking for a security lock (No `Win+L` please).

Has anyone seen something like this somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great program http://tk.ms11.net/

> Toddler Keys is a useful tool for parents that allows you to lock your computer keyboard, CD drive doors and power-off button. When the keyboard is used it will display images and play sounds every time a key is pressed, thereby preventing access to the desktop and applications, while adding some entertainment value for the kid. You can select the images and sounds to be used by copying them to the Toddler Keys folder. To exit the locked screen, just type the word QUIT.

Comment: Link does not work